# How to setup location as a geo_point in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, logstash, kibana, geopoints

I've been running into this issue where I get `failed to find geo_point field [location]`

Here is my flow.

1. Import csv

   ```
   input {
       file {
           path => "test.csv"
           start_position => "beginning"
           sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
       }
   }

   filter {
     csv {
       separator => ","
       #zip,lat, lon
       columns => [ "zip" , "lat", "lon"]
     }

     mutate {
       convert => { "zip" => "integer" }
       convert => { "lon" => "float" }
       convert => { "lat" => "float" }
     }

     mutate {
       rename => {
           "lon" => "[location][lon]"
           "lat" => "[location][lat]"
       }
     }

     mutate { convert => { "[location]" => "float" } }
   }

   output {
       elasticsearch {
           hosts => "cluster:80"
           index => "data"
       }
       stdout {}
   }
   ```
2. Test records

   ```
   GET data

   "hits": [
   {
     "_index": "data",
     "_type": "logs",
     "_id": "AVvQcOfXUojnX",
     "_score": 1,
     "_source": {
       "zip": 164283216,
       "location": {
         "lon": 71.34,
         "lat": 40.12
       }
     }
   },
   ...
   ```

If I try to run a `geo_distance` query I get `failed to find geo_point field [location]`

Then I try to run

```
PUT data
{
  "mappings": {
        "location": {
            "properties": {
                "pin": {
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get `index [data/3uxAJ4ISKy_NyVDNC] already exists`

How to I convert `location` into a `geo_point` so I can run the query on it?

edit:

I tried planting a template before i index anything, but still same errors

```
PUT _template/template
{
  "template": "base_map_template",
  "order": 1,
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "node_points": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name your template `data` instead of `base_map_template` since this is how your index is named. Also the type name needs to be `logs` instead of `node_points`:

```
PUT _template/template
{
  "template": "data",             <--- change this
  "order": 1,
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "logs": {                     <--- and this
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```